# Creating C# objects via MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, oop

I would like to get help from you, please :-)

I'm thinking about good way for programmatically creating of classes in C# via MySQL database.
In my app I'm creating composite classes. For example **Student**, **Classroom**, **Room** (dormitory) and so on. Class **Student** contains properties **Classroom** and **Room**. **ClassRoom** is also related to another entities in database...

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}

public class Classroom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

...etc
```

Usually when I need create object of some class, I must create also another classes' objects (sometime a part of database :-) ).

I think this way is not good optimalized, BUT there are great OOP benefits. When I load all students in a DataGridView, I can manage lots of related parts... for example:

```
Student student = ...

string currentTeacher = student.Classroom.Teacher.LastName   //... and so on.
```

**Is OK to create all related classes' objects immediately or is better create only necessary data of current created object and another data load / create "on demand"?**

Or absolutely different way? :-)

Comment: Note: Stackoverflow is allergic to opinion questions.  Also off the list are "can you suggest a tool" questions (take a look at the [help]).  In general what you are looking for is an _ORM_.  Standard recommendations would include _Dapper_ (https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) and the _Entity Framework_ (comes from Microsoft).  If you are a student, I think you can get the _Reverse POCO Generator_  (and EF add-on) for free (https://reversepoco.co.uk/)

Comment: Please also review the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin question on Meta that talks about "thanks" (and similar) text in the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, the idea is for you to make a query exactly like what you need an Ingress for a structural database like sql, talking a lot about the EntityFrame mappings where it is possible to query only the student object/table only by its id, however, if no process you will need the Classroom in which it belongs to you use a .Include() no entity and you would only be able to fetch the objects you will need in your request no problem mapping all entities as a bank into objects, the problem is to retrieve all of them from the relation since it only has a feature in some articles

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/querying/related-data
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

But if your purpose is performance, mount only the data you need in an object, just an example StudentInfo with the information you need grouped, use a Dapper to make the optimized query and make it do this mapping to your object, gaining performance

this is clear speaking of relational databases like Sql if your case is a NoSql database like MongoDb there is no problem in your mappings since it will return everything in a single document it is structured for this type of information there will be no InnerJoin cost between tables